# What is the meaning of the compiler error "variable x may not have been initialized"

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a Java Android program that can read and write to a file. I'm having some issues though. When the line at the very end is run, Eclipse tells me that my totalString variable may not have been initialized. However, I assign it a value inside the try loop. When I remove that last line and run my program, my console displays "Read File Successfully", as well as "java.io.FileInputStream@d77ffd1". That's definitely not the value I wrote to the file. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here and I'm kind of losing my mind lmao. Additionally, if I try to put a line like

```
totalString = "A Test Value"
```

In the try block, I still get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
            //lets try WRITING the file

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            String filename = "balance";
            String balanceString = "0.00";
            FileOutputStream outputStream;
            try {
                outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(balanceString.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error in Writing File.");
            }

            //lets try READING the file
            String totalString;
            FileInputStream inputStream;
            try {
                inputStream = openFileInput(filename);
                inputStream.read();
                inputStream.close();
                totalString = inputStream.toString();
                System.out.println("Read File Successfully");
                System.out.println(totalString);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error in Reading File.");
            }
            System.out.println(totalString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputStream.toString()` returns a **string representing the id of the `InputStream` object**. Not the data inside the file.

If you want the data inside the File which you are reading from the `InputStream`, you need to use built-in methods to read the file. The easiest way to do so is to wrap the `InputStream` object inside a `BufferedReader` (or any other `Reader` object), then use the `.readLine()` (or equivalent) method to get the data.

For example:

```
String totalString;
BufferedReader in;
try {
     in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(filename)));
     totalString = in.readLine();
     in.close();
     System.out.println("Read File Successfully");
     System.out.println(totalString);
    }
catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.out.println("Error in Reading File.");
    }
```

---

Now for output:

You could use the exact same technique as before, only changing the objects to their 'Writer' equivalents. For example:

```
PrintWriter out;
try {
     out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(penFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE))));
     out.println(balanceString);
     out.flush();
     out.close();
    }
catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.out.println("Error in Writing File.");
    }
```

The purpose of using the PrintWriter here in addition to the BufferedWriter is because it provides very easy to use methods (i.e. `println()`). Also, the 'flush()' method is used to make sure all the data in the stream gets written to the file, rather than 'getting stuck' in the buffer.

EDIT: Forgot to add a 'new' before the BufferedReader above. Fixed.

Comment: This works awesome! The only problem is that it now throws an exception when writing to the file...any suggestions?

Comment: You could do the same thing, just use a BufferedWriter + OutputStreamReader

Comment: I'll add an example to the answer, one sec

Comment: I understand the flush() method, as well as using the PrintWriter and BufferedWriter. however, the code that you gave me gives me 2 errors: "the method BuffredWriter(OutputStreamWriter) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}", with the 2nd error being identical, but with penFileOutput(String, int) being undefined

Comment: I made a small mistake. Fixed.

Comment: This works fantastically. Thank you so much. For future reference, if I wanted to save more than one value; i.e. an integer, the current time, and location, I'm sure I could do that as one write command. The question is how I could retrieve the values from a text file, and write them into an array? I don't really know how to word that well; are there any tutorials you could point me to?

Comment: For small amounts of data, it's easier to have each item (i.e time, location, etc.) on a separate line, because you could use 'readLine()' for each value individually. If you have lots of data or want to put them on the same line, look into either using a proper data storage format (i.e. JSON), or method's such as '.split()' for strings. You should learn arrays and file input/output separately, as it will be easier to understand. Check out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm and https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96202/discussion-between-bya413-and-bimde).

Answer (score 1):

inputStream.read() MIGHT throw an Exception. In this case, the variable MIGHT not have be initialized. Just change the declaration to

```
String totalString = null;
```

Alternatively you can move the System.out.println to the end of the try-block, where, when reached because no Exception is thrown, the variable is initialized.

Comment: Good analysis, but initializing the variable to a garbage value is rarely a good solution to such problems.  Yes, that silences the compiler, but the compiler was giving important information that should be meaninfully addressed, not ignored.

Comment: @John Bollinger: Correct. But having to assign a value should give a programmer hint enought that the variable will possibly have that value during the program flow.

Comment: If it's a garbage value that is assigned, then it is more useful to enable the compiler to *tell you* when you try to use it inappropriately than for you to make yourself write code to test that.  It is usually possible to avoid *both* assigning a dummy value and using the variable uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Also, read some tutorials about reading and writing files.

inputStream.read() will read a byte from the stream. But if you don't assign the return value of that function to a variable, it is discarded.

inputStream.toString() does what it says. It tries to describe the object, not the contents of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that

```
  FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(filename);

    ObjectOutputStream stringSaver = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);   

   stringSaver.writeObject(balanceString); 
   stringSaver.close();   
    outputStream.close();
```

All this in a try catch for saving in a file the String then load it with

```
         FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);  
         ObjectInputStream objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);   
         totalString = (String) objectStream.readObject();
         objectStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
```

this also in try catch...
It should work.
The problem solves that there was one variable may not have been initialized.

When you dont understand one part of the code be free to ask :D